# Node bcrypt / crypto package Salt and Secret change

Tags: node.js, bcrypt

Hi I'm trying to understand code that a previous develper wrote for a node.js app. I want to put the code into production and I want to know if I need to change the salt and secret that the developer added to the config.js and should salt & secret be stored in an .env file or is it OK in the config.js file ?

If salt & secret do need changing, is there a command that should be executed or can I simply edit the string ?

```
    const crypto = require('crypto');
    const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
    
    schemaObj.customerToken = crypto.createHash('sha1').update(uuidv4()).update(config.hidden.salt).digest('hex');
    schemaObj.customerSecret = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(uuidv4()).update(config.hidden.secret).digest('hex');
```

In the config.js file:

```
module.exports.hidden = {
    salt: 'a long random sting',
    secret: 'a very long random string'
}
```

Version of brypt

$ npm outdated
Package             Current   Wanted  Latest  Location
axios                0.19.2   0.19.2  0.25.0
bcrypt                4.0.1    4.0.1   5.0.1

Comment: Why has this question been given a mark down ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to deploy this code, the 'salt' and 'secret' strings in `config.js` should only be known by people you trust. Treat these like a password.

To change them, you could simply edit the string in `config.js`.

Comment: Can I change these stings to be any length ?

Comment: Yes, I think so. [This](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#hashupdatedata-inputencoding) is where I looked to check, and I don't think a maximum length is specified. The strings should be hard to attack in a similar way to a password - don't make them just 'password'! This article on [password entropy](https://www.okta.com/uk/identity-101/password-entropy/#:~:text=Password%20entropy%20is%20a%20measurement,top%20passwords%20used%20in%202021.) may be helpful.